# How many positive integers $a, b, c$ satisfy $a + 2b + 3c = 2016$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have to find the number of non-negative/positive integer solutions of
$$a + 2b + 3c = 2016.$$

I got this question and can't solve it, any hint?

Comment: i suppose they are positive, otherwise it is infinite

Comment: is $0$ valid?${}{}{}$

Answer (score 7):

The number of non-negative integer solutions of 
$$ a+2b+3c = 2016 $$
is given by the coefficient of $x^{2016}$ in the product
$$ (1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\ldots)(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+\ldots) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^3(1+x)(1+x+x^2)} $$
By partial fraction decomposition, the coefficient of $x^n$ is given by:
$$ \frac{1}{72} \left(47+9 (-1)^n+16\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3}\right)+36 n+6 n^2\right) $$
and by evaluating the previous expression at $n=2016$ we get that the number of non-negative integer solutions is $\color{red}{339697}$. In the same way, the number of positive integer solutions is given by $\color{purple}{338688}$.

This is just an instance of the well-known [money change problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoinProblem.html).

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\sum_{a = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{b = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{c = 0}^{\infty}
\delta_{a + 2b + 3c,2016}}\,\,\,\,\, =
\sum_{a = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{b = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{c = 0}^{\infty}
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{\color{#f00}{-}}}\,\,\,{1 \over z^{2017 - a - 2b - 3c}}
\,\,\,\,\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{\color{#f00}{-}}}\,\,\,{1 \over z^{2017}}
\pars{\sum_{a = 0}^{\infty}z^{a}}
\bracks{\sum_{b = 0}^{\infty}\pars{z^{2}}^{b}}
\bracks{\sum_{c = 0}^{\infty}\pars{z^{3}}^{c}}
\,\,\,\,\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{\color{#f00}{-}}}\,\,\,{1 \over z^{2017}}\,{1 \over 1 - z}\,
\,{1 \over 1 - z^{2}}\,\,{1 \over 1 - z^{3}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{z\ \mapsto\ 1/z}{=}\ &\
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{\color{#f00}{+}}}\,\,\,
{z^{2021} \over \pars{z - 1}\pars{z^{2} - 1}\pars{z^{3} - 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\end{align}
Inside the contour, the integrand poles $\ds{p}$'s belong to $\ds{\braces{-1,1,\expo{-2\pi\ic/3},\expo{2\pi\ic/3}}}$. The poles are single ones but $\ds{p = 1}$ is a pole of order three. The $\color{#f00}{residues}$ are given by:
$$
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rclcrcl}
\ds{p} & \ds{=} & \ds{-1} & \ds{\imp} &
\ds{\left.{z^{2021} \over \pars{z - 1}^{2}\pars{z^{3} - 1}}
\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ -1}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\color{#f00}{1 \over 8}}
\\[4mm]
\ds{p} & \ds{=} & \ds{\phantom{-}1} & \ds{\imp} &
\ds{{1 \over 2!}\lim_{z \to 1}\totald[2]{}{z}\bracks{%
{z^{2021} \over \pars{z + 1}\pars{z^{2} + z + 1}}}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\color{#f00}{24458159 \over 72}}
\\[4mm]
\ds{p} & \ds{=} & \ds{\phantom{-}\expo{\pm 2\pi\ic/3}} & \ds{\imp} &
\ds{\lim_{z \to \expo{\pm 2\pi\ic/3}}\,\,\,\,\,\,
{\pars{z - \expo{\pm 2\pi\ic/3}}z^{2021} \over \pars{z - 1}\pars{z^{2} - 1}\pars{z^{3} - 1}}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\color{#f00}{1 \over 9}}
\end{array}\right.
$$

---

The $\ \ul{final\ result}\ $ becomes:
$$
{1 \over 8} + {24458159 \over 72} + \pars{2 \times {1 \over 9}} =
\color{#f00}{339697}
$$

Comment: I wish you would explain what you're doing here because it looks beautiful but unclear to someone who's not familiar with these ideas. I mean no offense, but the post as is, is very difficult to understand. What do poles of the denominator have to do with the problem? What is $\delta_{a+2b+3b,2016}$ in the first sum?

Comment: @stressedout $\displaystyle\left. 1\right)$ The first $\displaystyle\color{red}{\texttt{triple sum}}$ takes into account all posibles triplets $\displaystyle\left(a,b,c\right)$ wich satisfy the proposed question: $\displaystyle\delta_{mn}$ is the $\displaystyle\texttt{Kronecker Delta}$. $\displaystyle\left. 2\right)$ The $\displaystyle\oint$ integral is a representation for the Kronecker Delta which let us to split the sums as independent ones. $\displaystyle\left. 3\right)$ The big $\displaystyle\brace$ just encloses the residues calculation for the $\displaystyle\texttt{final}$ integral.

Comment: @stressedout I hope my last comment clarifies your questions. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you xD Now I finally understand a little xD Why do you use the transformation $z \to 1/z$? And is there a particular reason that you have insisted on the notations $1^{\color{red}{-}}$ and $1^{\color{red}{+}}$? Could you also explain a bit about the step that you take the triple infinite sums inside the integral?

Answer (score 2):

Step-by-step solution (non-negative integers):

$c$ can take any of the integers $0,1,\ldots,\frac{2016}3=672$. There are $673$ choices (including the $0$).

Given $c$, $b$ can take any of the integers $0,1,\ldots,\left\lfloor\frac{2016-3c}2\right\rfloor$. There are $1+\left\lfloor\frac{2016-3c}2\right\rfloor$ choices (including the $0$).

Given $b$ and $c$, $a$ will be completely determined.

Hence the number of non-negative solutions is
$$\sum_{c=0}^{672}\left(1+\left\lfloor\frac{2016-3c}2\right\rfloor\right)$$
When $c$ is even, say $c=2k$ $(k=0,1,\ldots,336)$,
$\displaystyle \left\lfloor\frac{2016-3c}2\right\rfloor\ =\ \lfloor1008-3k\rfloor\ =\ 1008-3k$.

When $c$ is odd, say $c=2k-1$ $(k=1,\ldots,336)$,
$\left\lfloor\dfrac{2016-3c}2\right\rfloor\ =\ \left\lfloor1008-3k+\frac32\right\rfloor\ =\ 1009-3k$.

Hence the number of non-negative solutions is
$$\sum_{c=0}^{672}\left(1+\left\lfloor\frac{2016-3c}2\right\rfloor\right)$$
$$=\ \sum_{k=0}^{336}(1+1008-3k) \, + \, \sum_{k=1}^{336}(1+1009-3k)$$
$$=\ \boxed{339697}$$

For positive-integer solutions, similar steps apply.